Meaning of Markov kernel and being measurable function
In Wikipedia definition of Markov kernel, it says:

Markov kernel defined by a kernel function and a measure
Let ${\displaystyle \nu }$ be a measure on ${\displaystyle (Y,{\mathcal {B}})}$, and ${\displaystyle k : Y \times X → [0, \infty]}$ a measurable function with respect to the product ${\displaystyle \sigma }$-algebra ${\displaystyle {\mathcal {A}}\otimes {\mathcal {B}}}$ such that
$${\displaystyle \int _{Y}k(y,x)\nu (\mathrm {d} y)=1,\qquad \forall x\in X},$$

As I'm new to measure-theory, I'm only familiar with most standard definitions (such as this one). So the part about $k$ being measurable function seems unusual.
In my understanding, a measurable function has to be defined between measurable spaces. But in the definition above, there's nothing about the target being measurable (i.e. the event space on $[0,\infty]$ is not even defined)
Question
Is there a common assumption in this case? I also saw other cases where the definition of the target is simply left out. What would be a good way to infer the meaning.

Sets of (extended) real numbers are usually endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

I see. But there's still some confusion because it's unclear if they mean the target is measurable space (extended real numbers with sigma-algebra) which would make 'k' a measurable function or if they mean 'k' itself is a measure function. By looking at the definition, I'd think that 'k' is a measure function but the embedded URL's suggest that 'k' is a measurable function. What do you think?

Here, $k$ is a measurable function, not a kernel. But $k$ gives you conditional densities for a kernel. More precisely, there is a kernel that associates with each $x\in X$ the probability measure on $\mathcal{B}$ that assigns measure $\int_B k(\cdot,x)~\mathrm d\nu$ to $B$.
